# Trouble testing neo4j server module

Tags: maven, neo4j

I'm having difficulty writing a unit test for a neo4j un-managed extension I have written.

I am following the example at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions-testing.html

Problem is, the example uses an HTTP object and I cannot seem to import this from anywhere.

The official example indicates everything will be in the neo4j-harness dependency, however HTTP instead appears to be in neo4j-server. A fresh clone of the neo4j-server project does not build.

Rather than come up with an alternative, can anyone point me to a working version of neo4j-server I can include as a dependency in my pom?

I'm not having any luck with the likes of http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccontent.org.neo4j.app%7Cneo4j-server%7C2.2.3%7Cjar
when issuing `mvn clean install -U` and am instead getting a dependency resolution error.

Answer (score 1):

These are the dependencies I ran with in the end. Not documented anywhere that I know of and I am sure there is room for improvement so I have not marked this as correct, but they seem to work.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's is correct, because official documentation missing some piece.

Also I suggest to you use another library for testing Unmanaged extesions. It's opensource - https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/tests#graphunit